# DockerCompose networking isolation issue between two projects?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm encountering a strange issue with docker-compose on one of my systems.

I have two TICK (Telegraf, InfluxDB, Chronograf, Kapacitor) docker-compose "projects" on the same machine. Using the following [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/mgcrea/docker-compose-tick-stack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

Since both services are proxied behind the same NGINX SSL instance, they both join a common `nginx_proxy` external network.

Issue is that as soon as I start the second compose stack. Somehow the first stack starts misbehaving: a few (like 20%) requests from the first chronograf intance targeting the influxdb service via the `influxdb` hostname are somehow redirected to the influxb instance from the second stack.

I understand that since they are on the same nginx network, they can communicate, but how can I force the first instance to always target it's own service and not cross-compose? Tried to specify links but it did not work.

Any configuration I could setup to achieve this isolation without having to rename all my services?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect the embedded DNS server to do what you want automatically as it seems ambiguous to me (the docker-compose file doesn't express what you expressed in natural language here, which is perfectly fine and non-ambiguous). In fact I'm even surprised it allows it to run (seems to be doing round-robin across the containers, which would explain why only some requests are misrouted).

To answer your question, I would simply use non-ambiguous [aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) or just non-ambiguous service names, though there might be other solutions.

Comment: Slight update: The behavior you observe is actually somewhat documented in the aliases section: *"Note: A network-wide alias can be shared by multiple containers, and even by multiple services. If it is, then exactly which container the name will resolve to is not guaranteed."*. You should consider the service name to be a default network-wide name on par with aliases.